# how to do authorization in WCF C#

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, soapui

i have a WCF service, i can connect to it, but i cannot call it's method. the exception i get is 'The operation timed out.
but i can call it throw SoapUI very fast and without any error. in soap-ui i should add authorization to make it work :

[image]

what i did to solve the problem is:

-adding credentials :

```
communicationClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "XXXX";
communicationClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "XXXX";
```

-increasing time out :

```
communicationClient.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
communicationClient.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
```

-doing the same in app.config

they didn't work.

where i create and start the service (in client app) is :

```
private bool StartService()
                {
                        BasicHttpBinding hb = new BasicHttpBinding()
                        {
                                CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0),
                                //MaxBufferSize = 4096,
                                OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0),
                                ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0),
                                SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0),

                        };

                        EndpointAddressBuilder epb = new EndpointAddressBuilder()
                        {
                                Uri = new System.Uri("....myServiceUri....")
                        };

                        try
                        {
                                communicationClient = new SendLetterServiceClient(hb, epb.ToEndpointAddress());
                        }
                        catch (EndpointNotFoundException en) { throw en; }
                        catch (CommunicationException ce) { throw ce; }

                        communicationClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxxxxxxx";
                        communicationClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xxxxxxxx";
                        
                        communicationClient.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                        communicationClient.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

                        //communicationClient.
                        if (communicationClient.State != CommunicationState.Opened && communicationClient.State != CommunicationState.Opening)
                                communicationClient.OpenAsync();

                        return true;
                }
```

where i use it is :

```
public async Task<string> SendLetter(string nationalCode, string fileName, byte[] attachments)
                {
                        if (!serviceHasBeenStarted)
                        {
                         try{serviceHasBeenStarted = StartService();}
                         catch{throw new Exception("service has not been started, and can not restart it");}
                        }

                        string orgUserName = "XXXXXX";
                        string orgPassword = "XXXXXX";
                        string orgCode = "XXXX";
                        sendLetterAttach attachedLetter = new sendLetterAttach()
                        {
                                fileData = attachments,
                                fileName = fileName
                        };

                        try
                        {
                                var response1 = Task<getLetterTypeResponse>.Run(() =>
                                {
                                        return communicationClient.getLetterTypeAsync(
                                                                orgCode, orgUserName, orgPassword);
                                }).Result;

                                return response1.@return[0];
                        }
                        catch(Exception e1)
                        {
                                Console.WriteLine("error: \n\t" + e1.Message);
                        }
                        return "";
                }
```

when it calls the method, it waits for a minute, then throws exception.
i had added the service through 'add service reference' using visual studio in my .netCore solution.

...Ah! when i add the service, i get following warning:

```
Warning:Warning: No endpoints compatible with .Net Core apps were found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because core does not support **Message**:

```
        <binding name="Binding1">
          <security mode="Message">
              <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
```

The above binding configuration is not supported in core,if a service with the above binding configuration is added to the core, an error will be reported:

[image]

Core only supports None, Transport:

[image]

About core's support for WCF, you can refer to this link:

https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/tree/master/release-notes

**solution**

You need to change the **Message** of the server to **Transport**:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
      </security>
    </binding>        
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Username and password need to be added when the client is calling:

```
Client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
Client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "tset";
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

**UPDATE**

You can directly generate proxy classes through the Svcutil command:

[image]

Access the singlewsdl of the WCF service through the browser, and then save it locally.

[image]

Use Svcutil command to generate proxy class and configuration file.

[image]

Finally add them to your project.

Comment: thank you very much. i had added credentials you mentioned, but there are following problems: 1- i get new error: "The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="weblogic"'"   2- when i add service reference, i get that warning (about .netcore and you said that it is because of using message tag in app.config)  3- after adding service, it doesnt create app.config automatically. i make it and fill it myself. does it make any problem?  4- the service is made using java i think. is it problem?

Comment: What is the problem, can you provide some details?

Comment: i edited my comment. i provided more details there.

Comment: I update my reply.

Comment: thanks a lot again. i dont have service code, i just wrote a client. i used transport instead of username, i set username and password of client in code before calling, ... and there is no help. i think i should try to call soap-ui throw c#!!

Comment: i think this happens because the service ask user and password for two times! i have to enter user and password two times to add 'connected service' to project. it can make problem when application tries to call method, maybe

Comment: So you have been modifying the client?Did you modify the binding configuration on the client instead of the server?If you want to use core, you must modify the binding configuration of the server instead of modifying it on the client. I'm sorry that it may not be clear at the beginning. If you can't modify the server configuration, I suggest you use the .net framework.

Comment: If you only modify the binding configuration of the client instead of the server, the above problems will occur.

Comment: The binding configuration of the client and the binding configuration of the server must be the same.

Comment: There are two solutions: 1: modify the binding configuration of the server and then update the service reference on the client. 2: create the client using the .net framework.

Comment: the first solution is not available for me, because the service is one of organizational services which i have no access to its programmer or source code. and the 2nd solution is not available, i tried to, but i can't because it asks me credentials sequentially for hundreds of times and nothing happens. i dont know why

Comment: I update my reply.You need to know what credentials the service requires and then you can provide what kind of credentials. The client must be created with the .net framework.

Comment: thanks. i said that adding service to .net framework console was unsuccessful. it asks credentials again and again and again and .... i am trying to sniff traffic, to see the difference between soap-ui and what i generate in .net core

Comment: I update my reply.You can use another way to generate proxy classes.